# Using $_GET and URL to search

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I'm trying to filter data in my view based on URL parameters. I'm currently using basic Yii Ajax search in my view, which uses `$_POST` to get the results to display in `CGridView`.

`search()` method in my model is also a default one, using `CDbCriteria` and `compare()` to return `CActiveDataProvider` based on criteria submitted via mentioned search in view.

The grand **question** here is:

How can I perform search via URL which would look like `http://example.com/index.php/something/listAll?id=10&owner=numline1`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting the AJAX POST to work using the parameters passed in through the GET url string?

Comment: Not really, I need the search to work with URL/$_GET parameters, the $_POST is just a method I provided to explain how it works now. $_GET method should work without any ajax and just provide filtered data to a current view (in this case listAll).

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to filter data using the GET parameters without submitting those to your AJAX call so it know's what data to get.

Three's a strong chance I'm not understanding you though so apologies for that.

Comment: No problem, you may be actually correct. I'm not 100% sure what's the dataflow when submitting search form, but the point is that neither controller or anything within Ajax in my code checks for $_GET parameters at all. I believe that CGridView only gets already filtered records from controller, so I'd focus on that.

Comment: I'm not 100% on your actual process. But for me, I'd have my POST data simply getting the data that I require - if the GET parameters are set, I'd be passing those as a filter to the POST call. If that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it after some debugging. So it turns out, I need something like this in my controller:

```
if(isset($_GET['Book']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Book'];
else if(isset($_POST['Book']))
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Book'];
```

And the actual search URL will look like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/books/listAll?Book[id]=1234&Book[name]=Lorem%20Ipsum
```